# Why is my camera not working?

Tags: iphone, camera

[image: Camera screenshot]

I don't know why my camera is not working, I am sure it is a software problem, it just shows a black page. All features are working but it doesn't show an image. It is not working on other apps, like Instagram, as well.
The front camera is not working. I have tried to "Reset All Aetting" option but it is not working neither.
I upload a photo which is the screenshot when I run camera 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a case on the iPhone?  Is it blocking the lens?  Does the front camera work?

Comment: @bjbk  no, there is nothing to block the lenses. Front camera is not working.

Comment: Have you tried quitting the Camera App? Power cycling your phone?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz what do you mean by power cycling the phone ?

Comment: Turning it off and then on again

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz yeah, I did

Answer (score 1):

From another user's experience on the [Apple Support Community Forum:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6566551)

Try this:

- Go to **Settings > General** Reset
- Tap **Reset All Settings**

Although this won't erase content on your device, you'll have to reset WiFi settings and sign in to iCloud again along with other custom settings.

Quote:

> I was able to get the camera to work again!
>   go to Settings, General, Reset and tap Reset All Settings.
>   This won't erase everything but you'll have to set up your WiFi and sign in to iCloud again.

**EDIT** If the above suggestions along with resetting the phone etc. doesn't help, one would be advised to take the phone back to Apple or an Authorized Apple Service center for testing.  Depending on the age of the device, they may cover repairs under warranty.

Comment: based on what reputable source you got this information?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I updated my answer.  Reputability is questionable, but it may be the answer.

Comment: @bjbk as you said I have tried to reset all settings but there is no change and camera is not working yet. is there any other thing that I can try ?

Comment: You can take it to an Authorized service center at this point.

Answer (score 0):

After hearing about issues with the Flashlight app and reading several posts concerning issues with both iPhone 5 and the Flashlight app, it seemed logical to delete the Flashlight app. IPhone 5 camera seems to be working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my daughters ipod. I closed all apps and opened up again. I restarted the Ipod. I reset all settings. I backed it up and then erased everything with no results. In the end I have to take it to an apple store. Sometimes you just get a lemon.

Answer (score -2):

okay this sounds weird but it happened to me and it was a new case.... it could also be water damage but a new case or skin is probably the problem!!!:)