# Why is my camera app not working?

Tags: iphone, camera

[image]

I don't know why my camera is not working, I am sure it is a software problem, it just shows a black page.

All features are working but it doesn't show anything. It is not working on other apps, like Instagram, as well.
The front camera is not working.
I have tried the "Reset All Settings" option but there is no change and camera is not working yet.

I upload a photo that is a screenshot when I run camera.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: front or rear or both ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 both not working

Comment: For drastic measure such as Restore it is highly recommended to back up all your stuff first.

Comment: Should be covered under warranty too.

Comment: [Duplicate question.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/198829/120171) same user.

Comment: @bjbk because I didn't get the answer to solve the problem so I posted it again to see if any other has same experience or idea that can help me

Comment: You should have updated your original post with additional information, not create a new one.

Comment: If you edit your original question, with the screenshot for example, it moves up again. This site is different from a forum. But get advice on posting from some of the moderators. Hope you find a solution. Cheers

Comment: Ops, sorry I didn't know that, will do next time. Thanks guys

Comment: [This information regarding asking](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) when no one answers should help.

Comment: Please edit any additional information about the problem into your original question.